# Changing attributes after .append

Tags: javascript, jquery, append

I'm using a js to build a map and in this library all the html code is create from the javascript code, i'm putting some elements of my own inside the map div using the .append() function from jquery. I have to change the title of an icon after I create it (I'm using php to retrieve the title from my database that's why the function to change the title is in the main html) but it doesn't change... what am I doing wrong?

```
<div id="map"></div>

<script>
$("#blablabla").prop("title", "user2");
</script>
```

js

```
$("#map").append('<i id="blablabla" class="fa fa-user fa-3x" title="username"></i>');
```

I made an example of my problem on [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/andradegbz/9jvqdvr4/1/)

Comment: What is issue with code at Question?

Comment: the title of the icon have to be user2 but it wont change

Comment: The `title` is changed https://jsfiddle.net/9jvqdvr4/2/. Are you trying to change the property before the element is appended to the document?

Comment: Like I said in the question this part of the javascript must be in the main html cause I'm retrieving some info from my DB with PHP so in my original code is $("#userIcon").prop('title',"<?php echo $_SESSION['name']; ?>");

Comment: Is `$("#userIcon").prop('title',"<?php echo $_SESSION['name']; ?>");` called before `#userIcon` is appended to `document`?

Comment: I need to change the property after the element is appended

Comment: _"I need to change the property after the element is appended"_ Yes.

Comment: the order of the scripts is <script src="./scripts/widgets.control.js"></script> <script type="text/javascript">$("#userIcon").prop('title',"<?php echo $_SESSION['name']; ?>");</script>

Comment: Why are you using `"<?php echo $_SESSION['name']; ?>"`? Is `#userIcon` appended to `document` within `"./scripts/widgets.control.js"`?

Comment: The #userIcon is appended to div#map in the widgets.control, and i'm using php to retrieve the name of the user in the DB

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
$("#map").append('<i id="blablabla" class="fa fa-user fa-3x" title="username"></i>')
         .find('#blablabla').prop("title", "user2");
```

or

```
$("#map").append('<i id="blablabla" class="fa fa-user fa-3x" title="username"></i>');
$('#blablabla').prop("title", "user2");
```

Answer (score 0):

you should use attr function to change title of the tag

```
$("#map").append('<i id="blablabla" class="fa fa-user fa-3x" title="username"></i>');
$('#blablabla').attr("title", "user2");
```

Comment: I need to put the $('#blablabla').attr("title", "user2"); in the html so it still doesnt work

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer!
this piece of code worked for me [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9jvqdvr4/3/)

```
<script>
$(window).ready(function(){
    $("#blablabla").prop("title", "user2");
});

</script>
```